# JBPM and JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jbpm

I want to represent a business process that I will have from an XML file and represent it in a JPanel, and I need also to visualize its evolution in time by changing colors (for example). 
Do you know from where I should start, or if jBPMN can be connected to java and represented in my interface.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to find something that complex that you can easily put in a JPanel and expect it to work. I presume you want something like this? http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&id=4612  I once also used a system called ActiveVOS which used to do it (it had a dedicated web application which monitored the business processes and showed at which point they were visually, requests / responses sent etc.) But its commercial not open source.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll see it. I've seen before the Visualize paradigm software but as you said it is commercial not open source.

Answer (score 2):

The jBPM web designer can generate a PNG or SVG from an XML file (either by exporting as PNG or you can automatically save the SVG next to the process in the workbench repository when you save the process in designer.  Your JPanel could retrieve this process PNG or SVG, and annotate it by first querying the current state of your process (from the engine or the audit tables directly) and using that to highlight certain nodes for example.

For the next version of jBPM we're working on a REST call that would automate all of that for you.

Comment: Ok, I'll start with it and see if I can progress and realize my task. Tnx

Answer (score 0):

I think I am going to use JGraphix to draw my bpm, because as I saw, it give the possibility to draw shapes like bpmn ones.
I didn't see if it allows to change the color of the task case after x minut, but I guess it's going to be possible, and it's going to be the way to represent the evolution of the process at run time.

Do you think it's an Ok idea ?